# What options are there for "disabled" assistance at Heathrow airport? (or: which London airport is best for this?)

Tags: airports, london, lhr, accessibility

I want to bring my elderly parents to visit me here in Sweden next year. My father has had a stroke and walks with a walking stick, and my mother has back issues. Neither of them are in a wheelchair, but they both find it very difficult to walk even moderate distances (they're tired out after 100 meters). In my experience, getting from check-in to the gates at Heathrow can be a marathon and a half for myself, so I'm worried about them making it alone.

Will Heathrow be able to offer any services for my parents to help them get from the check-in to the gate area? I would be willing to pay for such a service. If not, do any of the other London airports serving Sweden provide any disabled services?

They have the disabled car badge thing and are on disability benefits, so proving that they have issues should not be an issue (I think).

Comment: The important bit is to refuse to get of the airplane until the wheelchair as arrived, as once you are off the airline may not be very interested.

Comment: As far as I understand you get help when you apply for it, often people in need of help have temporary problems, like a broken leg, and a lot of the problems are not visible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Heathrow Airport provides golf buggies for passengers with mobility issues, I have seen these in operation. You may have to [request special assistance from your airline at least 48 hours in advance](http://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/special-assistance/how-to-get-help). The key point is that your **airline** is responsible for ensuring boarding assistance, they should be the ones you liaise with. Heathrow also provides porterage for "reasonable amounts of luggage").

[This site has links to accessibility pages of airports in the UK](http://www.disabledholidaydirectory.co.uk/about/uk-airport-accessibility.html) - you'll find links to other London-area airports. [Walking distance to gates is probably least for London City airport](https://www.londoncityairport.com/intheairport/page/reduced-mobility-and-special-assistance). Given the volume of passengers though you'll probably be better off with Heathrow as both airlines and airport staff will be aware of procedures.

Comment: Note: The *airline* needs 48 hours notice, not the airport. Help is always available at Heathrow itself. In the first link provided by Ankur, see the section "At the airport" after the sentence "When you get to the airport help is always at hand in the following areas..."